# Solr: calculating the difference between two given dates when one of the values is *

Tags: php, search, solr

I'm working on something that when a range filter is active, the range facets will update accordingly. If no filter is given, I'm using a default range & gap. If a filter is set I do a second solr call to recalculate the facet range gap.

So for example at first I show range facets of a gap of 10YEARS. When you filter one of those, it shows 10 range facets of 1YEAR. If you filter again, it'll show 12 buckets with a 1 month range etc...

It kind of works, but I'm having trouble when the range filter includes a *. Solr knows how to correctly filter results when solrfield:[1960-01-01T00:00:00Z TO *] is given, but I don't know how I recalculate the date range facet gaps based on *. Right now I calculate the difference between the two dates as a unix timestamp and calculate the range gap based on that.

Also, is there a name for what I'm trying to do here? I'd call it 'variable range gaps', but I'm not sure if that's correct.

I'm not even sure if what I'm doing is the best approach. Any advice is welcome.

Edit: what my question comes down to is: I would like to calculate difference (as unix timestamp) between the highest and lowest date of a field in every solr query.

Edit 2: Every solr call I do takes about 300ms (on a relatively small index). That's quite a bit in case I do 2 extra calls with a date sort to find the highest and lowest date value in the query. Then performing the 4th solr call with the correct date gap (and from/to values), would get a bit slow.

Comment: The only way I can think of to do that would be to use faceting on the date field and set `facet.limit=-1` (or any other negative number). But that might be unworkable for you since it will bring back every value for that date along with the # of records for each value.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably turn it into familiar "limited date range" case. If it is impossible for your data to have datetime set in the future, your can replace * with NOW always receiving the same resultset (as no date can be later than current moment) and calculate gaps basing on current timestamp.